# Why can I use VS code with anaconda only when I open it from anaconda navigator?

Tags: python, visual-studio-code, anaconda

I know this question is frequently asked, but none of the answers solved my problem.

I use VS code for bunch of things : Python, html css javascript php, Ruby etc.
I use anaconda for Python. However, I can only run python with anaconda when I open VS code by the anaconda navigator.

I tried the to do the same thing as it automatically does with anaconda navigator :
Setting the same interpreter, the good language etc.
But when I try `conda activate base` (which is automatically written with anaconda and works), it gives me an error. It's not an huge problem, but it's just annoying to open anaconda everytime. What should I do ?

Comment: is anaconda path added to your windows path?

Comment: No I don't think so

Answer (score 0, accepted):

make sure you have your anaconda path added to the windows path.

to add anaconda to the windows path follow this:

1. search "environment" in windows search.
2. click on "environment variables"
   [image]
3. in the system variables area. look for "path" variable. select it and click on edit.
   [image]
4. add the following (make sure the addresses are correct in your case first).
   [image]

if you do not know where is anaconda installed on your PC. open cmd from anaconda navigator and write "where conda"